# JAVA text based menu not returning to root menu

Tags: java, menu

I'm generating a menu driven calculation program for one of my classes and I'm trying to figure why my submenu won't return back to the root menu after its complete.  With the main argument set, options 1-4 and 6 work fine as intended.  Option 5 will pull up the sub menu and queue the correct response but then just dumps back in the the submenu loop.  What am I missing or is there a way to break and return to root without terminating the program?  Thanks for the help!

Main Argument:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      Final_Project project = new Final_Project();
      int selection = 0;
      while (selection != 6)
      {
         selection = project.mainMenu();
         if (selection == 1)
            project.addition();
         else if (selection == 2)
            project.subtraction();
         else if (selection == 3)
            project.multiplication();
         else if (selection == 4)
            project.division();
         else if (selection == 5)
         {
            project.subMenu();
            int subSelection = 0;
            while (subSelection != 2)
            {
               subSelection = project.subMenu();
               if (subSelection == 1)
                  project.displayAdditionTable();
               else if (subSelection == 2)
                  project.displayMultiplicationTable();
               else
                  System.out.println("Invalid menu options selected, try again\n");
            }
         }
         else if (selection == 6)
            project.exitProgram();
         else
            System.out.println("Invalid menu options selected, try again.\n");
      }
   }
```

Main menu:

```
  private int mainMenu()   
   {   
      Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Welcome to the Java Calculator!\n");
      System.out.println("MAIN MENU\n");
      System.out.println("1.   Addition");
      System.out.println("2.   Subtraction");
      System.out.println("3.   Multiplication");
      System.out.println("4.   Division");
      System.out.println("5.   Display Study Tables");
      System.out.println("6.   Exit\n");
      System.out.println("Please select an option from the menu:");

      return kb.nextInt();
   }
```

Sub Menu:

```
 private int subMenu()   
   {   
      Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Display Study Tables selected:\n");
      System.out.println("SUB MENU\n");
      System.out.println("1.   Addition");
      System.out.println("2.   Multiplication");
      System.out.println("Please select an option from the menu:");

      return kb.nextInt();
   }
```

Table place holder example:

```
private void displayAdditionTable()
   {
      System.out.println("Display Study Tables selected:\n");      
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple things wrong with your selection == 5 block.

- You make a call to project.subMenu() at the start of the loop but don't do anything with the return value. So at the bare minimum the menu is going to display twice.
- You only break out of the loop when subSelection == 2, so the sub menu will keep displaying until the user selects the multiplication option.

I don't want to write the code for you since this is for a class, but I would see if you can move all of the submenu code, including the loop, into the subMenu() method and only call project.subMenu() from the main loop. Otherwise, the main loop has to know too much information about what the submenu's options are and what it should return, which is bad encapsulation.